# using > instead of stdout

Tags: c++

So for my program I need to take all the informations that are shown in cmd.exe and put them on a file.
So for that I used the following code

```
freopen ("text.txt","w",stdout);
```

and I had to put it in the main.cpp

However I was told that I should do that in a diffrent class and that I could use the `>` symbol directly.

Could you guys tell me how I can do that?

If you could give me an example that would be great.

Comment: I think you were told to print the information to the standard output, and use the shell's redirection operator `>` to redirect the standard output to the file of your choice when invoking your program.

Answer (score 3):

I think you were told about pipes. In you shell, you can type something like:

```
somecommand > text.txt
```

And it will write the output of `somecommand` into `text.txt`.

Comment: yes but I have to do that in the C++ program not in the shell and that's what I don't know how to do

Comment: The ">" character has no I/O related meaning in C++... it's familiar from Operating System shells, and you explicitly mention exactly that (albeit a lame one) in "cmd.exe".  You should read the links NtscCobalt provides then sit down with whomever's telling you how to do this, and it might just make sense.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::cout << "Output sentence"; // prints Output sentence on screen
std::cout << 120;               // prints number 120 on screen
std::cout << x;                 // prints the content of x on screen
```

If you use those then the user can redirect your output (which will normally go to the console) to a file instead by using the syntax below.

```
yourapplication.exe > "output.txt"
```

If you use std::cin with the << operator then you can also `< "input.txt"` to enter text from input.txt as if the user typed it.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/ explain the input and output streams fairly well.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx explains console redirection.